# Is Instagram stories in UICollectionView or UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I want to make stories like app. I see that some people say `UIPageViewController` meant to limited views. What I found is also that loading images are slow in `UIPageViewController` when scroll to another.
What are the differences between `UICollectionView` or `UIPageViewController`? When to use one over another?

What should I use to make stories like app?

Comment: "loading images are slow in UIPageViewController" If you are using asynchronous image loading, this should not be a problem.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that they are not using a UICollectionView for this. My guess is a UIPageViewController-like mechanism with custom transitions between pages.

Comment: UIPageViewController  support custom transition animators?

Answer (score 2):

Instagram is a collection view. The don't use tableviews at all. Here is an open source library from instagram that is used to power their apps:

https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit

Also I attach a screenshot taken from there reference guide.

[image]

And the url:

https://instagram.github.io/IGListKit/getting-started.html

Comment: we are not talkind about tableviews, instead pageviewcontroller here.

Comment: @John yes I see, but people usually think the feed is a Tableview, but the IG stories as the feed are CollectionViews